# Size of vocabulary SpaCy model 'en_core_web_sm'

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-science, spacy

I tried to see the number of words in vocabulary in SpaCy small model:

```
model_name="en_core_web_sm"

nlpp=spacy.load(model_name)

len(list(nlpp.vocab.strings))
```

which only gave me 1185 words. I also tried in my colleagues' machines and gave me different results (1198 and 1183).

Is it supposed to be like this to have only such a small vocabulary to train Part-Of-Speech tagging? When I use this in my dataset, I lose a lot of words. Why the number of words vary in different machines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vocabulary is dynamically loaded so you don't have all the words in the StringStore when you first load the vocab.  You can see this if you try the following...

```
>>> import spacy
>>> nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
>>> len(nlp.vocab.strings)
1180
>>> 'lawyer' in nlp.vocab.strings
False
>> doc = nlp('I am a lawyer')
>>> 'lawyer' in nlp.vocab.strings
True
>>> len(nlp.vocab.strings)
1182
```

It's probably easiest to simply load the vocabulary from the raw file like this..

```
>>> import json
>>> fn = '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/spacy/data/en/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0/vocab/strings.json'
>>> with open(fn) as f:
>>>     strings = json.load(f)
>>> len(strings)
78930
```

Note that the above file location is for Ubuntu 18.04.  If you're on Windows there will be a similar file but in a different location.