# The length of the vocabulary of Spacy 'en_core_web_sm'

Tags: nlp, spacy

I am using a macbook and trying to learn NLP from a udemy course. The length of my space library is `len(doc.vocab)=532` , however in the video same length is around 57000. I downloaded the larger version as well nothing changed.

Comment: Look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58722405/size-of-vocabulary-spacy-model-en-core-web-sm

Comment: Note that in general the size of the Vocab is an implementation detail and you shouldn't rely on it for much of anything.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`len(doc.vocab)` is the number of cached lexemes, which can therefore vary when you use the model on some words.

`len(doc.vocab.strings)` maps strings to hash values, and vice versa. It can give you the number of different strings. For the model `en_core_web_md`, this would give you 701800 for example.

Comment: The instructor of the course insists that this line of code should brings much higher value. 
'import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp(u"The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.")
len(doc.vocab) = 504'